# How should I write a decryption program for this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii

I am trying to write an decryption code using Python. The encryption works and outputs the following 119105108108 116104105115 11911111410763 for the words "will this work? in a file called myfile. But i have no idea how to decrypt it or whether it can even be decrypted and would love some help.

```
#declare variables
fo = 0
ascii_val = []
asci_val = []
asc_val = []
listtostr = 0
listtost = 0
listtos = 0
split_val = 0
x = 0

#open files
fo = open("myfile.txt","r")
fo1 = open("hora.txt","w")

#read text from files and put into a list    
txt = fo.read()
split_val = txt.split(" ")
print(split_val)

#process of encrypting using ascii values
for x in split_val[0]:
    y = x.split()
    a = ord(x)
    a =str(a)
    ascii_val.append(a)
    
print()

#process
for x in split_val[1]:
    a = ord(x)
    a =str(a)
    asci_val.append(a)
    
print()

#process
for x in split_val[2]:
    a = ord(x)
    a =str(a)
    asc_val.append(a)
    
#joining ascii values together
listtostr = "".join([str(x) for x in ascii_val])

listtost = "".join([str(x) for x in asci_val])

listtos = "".join([str(x) for x in asc_val])

#joining all of the ascii values together
b = listtostr + " " + listtost +" " + listtos
print(b)

#writing to new file
fo1.write(b)

#close files
fo.close()
fo1.close()
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of cipher was used for the encryption?

Comment: i used ord() to turn each letter into a value.

Comment: well the oposite of ord() is chr().  Whats wrong with using that? You will need to seperate the numbers with spaces or commas or some other delimeter so you know how which digits belong to which value.

Comment: By the way, if you simply represent something as something else without a key, it's called *encoding* and *decoding*. For encryption / decryption you'd require a key or key pair. If you just make the text unreadable then you could argue that it is still cryptography (which literally means hidden writing) but commonly we'd call that *obfuscation* in the security field.